# Couldn't install BDR-postgres on centos7

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-bdr

Followed all steps from the documetation untill the below command,where it got struck.

sudo yum install postgresql-bdr94-bdr

It returns error message saying "NO package postgresql-bdr94-bdr available"

Comment: Have you tried with 2ndQuadrant instructions? https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/bdr/bdr-installation-instructions/

Comment: Yes, I was following the same one

Answer (score 0):

have you activated the bdr repo?

```
sudo yum install https://rpm.2ndquadrant.com/site/content/2ndquadrant-repo-bdr9.4-1-1.el7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum repolist
sudo yum check-update
sudo yum install postgresql-bdr94-bdr
```

you can install packages when you activate 2ndquadrant bdr repos.

Comment: No longer works. Fails with

Status code: 404 for https://dl.2ndquadrant.com/default/release/rpm/site/content/2ndquadrant-repo-bdr9.4-1-1.el7.noarch.rpm